# jQuery move effect

Tags: jquery, html

I need help with jQuery effects, after setting images to a position through style, and user can drag the images around after the html page published, I need some plugin or a command to make jQuery return the image, which has been dragged, to it's original position.

For ex. if the user moved b1  to another position, b1 will return slowly to it's original position.

Here is the link to the page: [Draggable images](http://ayyashsigns.com/lab/circles.html)

Thanx in advance,

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this? http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#revert

Just set the revert option to true: `$("#b1").draggable({ revert: true });`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `revert: true` option of the draggable plugin. This will cause the element to always return to its original location after dragging has finished

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`revert` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#revert).

Comment: Doesn't that revert immediately, not slowly as requested?

Comment: Wish I could. But jQueryUI drag-and-drop doesn't work on iPads. :-)

Comment: Ah. Just saw the `revertDuration` option in the documentation, which defaults to 500. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

In your jQuery code, where you specify what is draggable, add `{ revert: true }`

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/VV4CE/
and the documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind to the "dragstop" event and then start a slow animation to return the element to it's original position.